# Removing switch that turns on / off the outlet

Tags: electrical, switch, receptacle

I have an outlet which gives electricity only when corresponding wall switch is on. I need to remove the wall switch because I need to put a cabinet on it's place. How do I make the outlet permanently "on"? Is it enough to just connect together Live and Neutral wire in the switch, then remove the switch? In other words, would it make a short circuit? :)

Comment: if you removed the switch the box must remain accessible so you can't put a cabinet in fron of it

Comment: Why would it have to remain accessible? I just want to make it permanently "on", like all other outlets.

Comment: All junction boxes must remain accessible removing the switch and connecting the live to the switched live and closing it up makes the spot where it was a junction box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Turn off the breaker
2. Remove the face plate.  You should find two (usually) black wires on opposite ends of the switch.
3. Remove the switch, and join the two black wires with a wire nut.
4. Turn on the breaker, and test the outlet
5. Put a blank face plate on the (now junction block)
6. Install cabinets
7. Cut a hole in the back of the cabinet to access the junction box.

Comment: Don't you need to cap the ground wire as well between step 3 and 4?